# Keeping axes synchronized when stacking two XYCharts

Tags: javafx

I want to stack two different XYCharts as done [here](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3668862).

In this example however, the bounds of the axes are the same and data is static.

In my case, I have dynamic data to plot: new values are added to the data series as they become available. So the y axis (for instance) gets updated when new data arrives.

Moreover, the two data sets are not exactly in the same range.

Here is a first attempt:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to draw layers of XYCharts.
 * https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2435995 "Using StackPane to layer more different type charts"
 */
public class LayeredXyChartsSample extends Application {

    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> barSeries;
    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> lineSeries;


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        initSeries();

        // Close the application when the window is closed
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        layerCharts(
                                createBarChart(),
                                createLineChart()
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();

        updateSeries();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initSeries() {
        barSeries = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data("Jan", 2),
                        new XYChart.Data("Feb", 10),
                        new XYChart.Data("Mar", 8),
                        new XYChart.Data("Apr", 4),
                        new XYChart.Data("May", 7),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4),
                        new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8),
                        new XYChart.Data("Sep", 16.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13.9),
                        new XYChart.Data("Nov", 17),
                        new XYChart.Data("Dec", 10)
                )
        );

        lineSeries = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1),
                        new XYChart.Data("Feb", 2),
                        new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3),
                        new XYChart.Data("May", 2.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4),
                        new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8),
                        new XYChart.Data("Sep", 6.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13),
                        new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10),
                        new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20)
                )
        );
    }

    private void updateSeries() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final int index = i;
                final double value = 20 * Math.random();
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    barSeries.getData().remove(0);
                    barSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(String.valueOf(index), value));

                    lineSeries.getData().remove(0);
                    lineSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(String.valueOf(index), value * 2));
                });
            }

            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }).start();
    }

    private NumberAxis createYaxis() {
        final NumberAxis axis = new NumberAxis();
        axis.setAutoRanging(true);
        axis.setPrefWidth(35);
        axis.setMinorTickCount(10);

        axis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(axis) {
            @Override public String toString(Number object) {
                return String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
            }
        });

        return axis;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private BarChart<String, Number> createBarChart() {
        final BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), createYaxis());
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.getData().addAll(barSeries);
        return chart;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LineChart<String, Number> createLineChart() {
        final LineChart<String, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), createYaxis());
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getData().addAll(lineSeries);
        return chart;
    }

    private void setDefaultChartProperties(final XYChart<String, Number> chart) {
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private final StackPane layerCharts(final XYChart<String, Number>... charts) {
        for (int i = 1; i < charts.length; i++) {
            configureOverlayChart(charts[i]);
        }

        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        stackpane.getChildren().addAll(charts);

        return stackpane;
    }

    private void configureOverlayChart(final XYChart<String, Number> chart) {
        chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
        chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);

        chart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/overlay-chart.css").toExternalForm());
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The Y axis is not looking good: there are two axes and as they don't have the same bounds anymore, they don't overlay properly.

Next attempt consists in creating a single axis and assigning it to both charts. A few changes:

- a class variable is created: `private NumberAxis yAxis;`
- the `createYaxis` method is modified as follows (it's a void method and sets the variable):

  private void createYaxis() {
      yAxis = new NumberAxis();
      yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
      yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
      yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);

  ```
  yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {
      @Override public String toString(Number object) {
          return String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
      }
  });
  ```

  }
- the `createYaxis` method is called at the end of the `initSeries` method.
- the charts are created with the same yAxis, e.g.:

  BarChart chart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), yAxis);

Now, the yAxis looks good, but the graphs are not displayed on the same scale as soon as a new value for the line chart exceeds the axis bounds (note that the new line series values are 2x those of the bar series new values; the chart does not take it into account).

[image]

So my next move would be to create a BoundAxis class that takes a reference axis and update it's bound when the reference axis bounds are modified. Something like this:

```
public class BoundAxis<T> extends Axis<T> {

    private final Axis<T> originalAxis;

    public BoundAxis(Axis<T> originalAxis) {
        this.originalAxis = originalAxis;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object autoRange(double length) {
        return originalAxis.autoRange(length); // Compilation error
    }

    @Override
    protected void setRange(Object range, boolean animate) {
        originalAxis.setRange(range, animate); // Compilation error
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getRange() {
        return originalAxis.getRange(); // Compilation error
    }

    @Override
    public double getZeroPosition() {
        return originalAxis.getZeroPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public double getDisplayPosition(T value) {
        return originalAxis.getDisplayPosition(value);
    }

    @Override
    public T getValueForDisplay(double displayPosition) {
        return originalAxis.getValueForDisplay(displayPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValueOnAxis(T value) {
        return originalAxis.isValueOnAxis(value);
    }

    @Override
    public double toNumericValue(T value) {
        return originalAxis.toNumericValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public T toRealValue(double value) {
        return originalAxis.toRealValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<T> calculateTickValues(double length, Object range) {
        return originalAxis.calculateTickValues(length, range); // Compilation error
    }

    @Override
    protected String getTickMarkLabel(T value) {
        return originalAxis.getTickMarkLabel(value); // Compilation error
    }
}
```

But this does not compile, because there are protected methods I cannot call.

One last thing, I want something rather generic: the BoundAxis must be extend Axis so I can ue it with not only the NumberAxis.

**Edit:** This question is related to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022601/how-to-clone-x-and-y-axis).

Comment: Just to be clear. You are trying to overlap two `Charts` whose data have no relationship?

Comment: They do. For instance, you might want to plot the Bollinger bands: https://tradingsim.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Bollinger-Bands-768x305.png : they are related, but don't have the same range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found. Basically, I set the upper and lower bounds manually.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to draw layers of XYCharts.
 * https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2435995 "Using StackPane to layer more different type charts"
 */
public class LayeredXyChartsSample extends Application {

    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> barSeries;
    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> lineSeries;

    private NumberAxis yAxis;
    private double lowerBound = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    private double upperBound = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        initSeries();

        // Close the application when the window is closed
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(t -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        layerCharts(
                                createBarChart(),
                                createLineChart()
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();

        updateSeries();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initSeries() {
        barSeries = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data("Jan", 2),
                        new XYChart.Data("Feb", 10),
                        new XYChart.Data("Mar", 8),
                        new XYChart.Data("Apr", 4),
                        new XYChart.Data("May", 7),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4),
                        new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8),
                        new XYChart.Data("Sep", 16.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13.9),
                        new XYChart.Data("Nov", 17),
                        new XYChart.Data("Dec", 10)
                )
        );

        lineSeries = new XYChart.Series(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data("Jan", 1),
                        new XYChart.Data("Feb", 2),
                        new XYChart.Data("Mar", 1.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Apr", 3),
                        new XYChart.Data("May", 2.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jun", 5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Jul", 4),
                        new XYChart.Data("Aug", 8),
                        new XYChart.Data("Sep", 6.5),
                        new XYChart.Data("Oct", 13),
                        new XYChart.Data("Nov", 10),
                        new XYChart.Data("Dec", 20)
                )
        );

        createYaxis();
    }

    private void updateSeries() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final int index = i;
                final double value = 20 * Math.random();

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    barSeries.getData().remove(0);
                    barSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(String.valueOf(index), value));

                    lineSeries.getData().remove(0);
                    lineSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(String.valueOf(index), value * 2));

                    lowerBound = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    upperBound = Double.MIN_VALUE;

                    for (int j = 0; j < barSeries.getData().size(); j++) {
                        lowerBound = Math.min(lowerBound, barSeries.getData().get(j).getYValue().doubleValue());
                        lowerBound = Math.min(lowerBound, lineSeries.getData().get(j).getYValue().doubleValue());

                        upperBound = Math.max(upperBound, barSeries.getData().get(j).getYValue().doubleValue());
                        upperBound = Math.max(upperBound, lineSeries.getData().get(j).getYValue().doubleValue());
                    }

                    yAxis.setLowerBound(lowerBound);
                    yAxis.setUpperBound(upperBound);
                });
            }

            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }).start();
    }

    private void createYaxis() {
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setPrefWidth(35);
        yAxis.setMinorTickCount(10);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(20);

        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis) {
            @Override public String toString(Number object) {
                return String.format("%7.2f", object.floatValue());
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private BarChart<String, Number> createBarChart() {
        final BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), yAxis);
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.getData().addAll(barSeries);
        return chart;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private LineChart<String, Number> createLineChart() {
        final LineChart<String, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), yAxis);
        setDefaultChartProperties(chart);
        chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        chart.getData().addAll(lineSeries);
        return chart;
    }

    private void setDefaultChartProperties(final XYChart<String, Number> chart) {
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    private final StackPane layerCharts(final XYChart<String, Number>... charts) {
        for (int i = 1; i < charts.length; i++) {
            configureOverlayChart(charts[i]);
        }

        StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
        stackpane.getChildren().addAll(charts);

        return stackpane;
    }

    private void configureOverlayChart(final XYChart<String, Number> chart) {
        chart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
        chart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.getXAxis().setVisible(false);
        chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);

        chart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/overlay-chart.css").toExternalForm());
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a little note that one doesn't need to write source code to stack charts over eachother: You can also set the attributes without events and threading within the FXML file as shown below:

```
<BarChart fx:id="bc_stock_c" alternativeRowFillVisible="false" animated="false" horizontalZeroLineVisible="false" legendVisible="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" title="Produkt C" verticalGridLinesVisible="false" verticalZeroLineVisible="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    <xAxis>
        <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis animated="false" autoRanging="false" lowerBound="0.0" minorTickCount="100" prefHeight="135.0" prefWidth="35.0" side="LEFT" tickUnit="100.0" upperBound="1000.0" />
    </yAxis>
</BarChart>
<LineChart fx:id="lc_demand_c" alternativeRowFillVisible="false" animated="false" createSymbols="false" horizontalGridLinesVisible="false" horizontalZeroLineVisible="false" legendVisible="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" stylesheets="@style.css" title=" " verticalGridLinesVisible="false" verticalZeroLineVisible="false" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    <xAxis>
        <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis>
        <NumberAxis animated="false" autoRanging="false" lowerBound="0.0" minorTickCount="100" prefHeight="135.0" prefWidth="35.0" side="LEFT" tickUnit="100.0" upperBound="1000.0" />
    </yAxis>
</LineChart>
```

Just set pref_width, pref_height, autoRanging, minorTickCount, tickUnit, upperBound and lowerBound for each Y-axis and it should work. You also should add the following css style to make the chart area transparent for each line chart:

```
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```